# Weird behaviour of M-; (`comment-dwim`) in Autoconf-mode

Tags: comment, autoconf-mode

When editing an Autoconf (`configure.ac`) file I observe strange behaviour when using `M-;` (`comment-dwim`) to uncomment a selected region. When a region with comments is selected `comment-dwim` calls `uncomment-region`, so maybe the problem is in that function.

Commenting a region works as expected:

```
# ACML
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(dgemm, acml_mp,
   [found_blas=1 AM_CPPFLAGS="-D_acml_ $AM_CPPFLAGS"],
   [AC_MSG_NOTICE([NOT using AMD the ACML library])],
   [-lgfortran]
)
```

becomes:

```
dnl # ACML
dnl AC_SEARCH_LIBS(dgemm, acml_mp,
dnl    [found_blas=1 AM_CPPFLAGS="-D_acml_ $AM_CPPFLAGS"],
dnl    [AC_MSG_NOTICE([NOT using AMD the ACML library])],
dnl    [-lgfortran]
dnl )
```

However, when trying to uncomment the region, the result is:

```
dnl ACML
dnl AC_SEARCH_LIBS(dgemm, acml_mp,
   [found_blas=1 AM_CPPFLAGS="-D_acml_ $AM_CPPFLAGS"],
dnl    [AC_MSG_NOTICE([NOT using AMD the ACML library])],
   [-lgfortran]
dnl )
```

Did I miss something or have I hit a bug?

Comment: Testing this in Emacs 24.4 (-Q) and I do not see this behavior. The comments are added and removed on each line.

Comment: Hmm, Emacs 24.3.1 here. The problem is present even when using `-Q`. I probably should start looking for a Emacs 24.4 repo for Ubuntu...

Comment: Sounds like a bug (regression) in 24.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in Emacs 23.4, reproduced in Emacs 24.3.

This is [Bug #14046](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=14046), with no resolution as I write.

I think it's a duplicate of [Bug #15822](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15822), which is fixed by [revision 115027 to `autoconf.el`](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/emacs-24/revision/115027) released in Emacs 24.4.

Comment: Thank you for digging into this and pointing to the bug reports and resolution.